# Update data assigned to global variable (outside callback) once a day

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am creating a read-only Plotly Dash dashboard that uses a lot of data. It involves a lot of database reads and transformations which usually takes up to 1 minute. To avoid user waiting this long on every interaction, I am performing these steps outside the callbacks and assign the data to a global variable. These steps are performed only once when the first user opens the dashboard.

The dashboard has filters. When the user changes the filters, I filter the global data (in a different variable) based on the selected filters in the callback functions and display the data. As the data is already available on the server, subsequent interactions are fast. The global data is not updated from the callbacks. This work great and it performs well.

The data I am using has daily granularity. I need to update this global data once a day to ensure that the global data is up-to-date. How do I update this global data? I think I can use Redis as an intermediate store which is updated once a day and all callbacks read from Redis but can this be done without the intermediate layer?

Here is the sample code:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback
import pandas as pd
from dash_ag_grid import AgGrid

def get_global_data():
    data_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Lot of DB reads and transformations
    return data_df

global_data = get_global_data()

app = Dash(__name__)



app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H6("Select country to view data!"),
    dcc.Dropdown(['USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico'], 'USA', id='country-dropdown'),
    html.Br(),
    AgGrid(
        id="data-grid",
        defaultColDef={"resizable": True, "sortable": True, "filter": True},
        columnSize="sizeToFit",
        style={'width': '100%'},
    )

])


@callback(
    Output('data-grid', 'rowData'),
    Output('data-grid', 'columnDefs'),
    Input(component_id='country-dropdown', component_property='value')
)
def update_table(input_country):
    filtered_data = global_data[global_data['country']==input_country]
    filtered_data_as_dict = convert_df_to_dict(filtered_data) # convert to dict
    column_defs = create_column_def(filtered_data)  # generates column def
    return filtered_data_as_dict, column_defs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If global data in this code is updated daily, how do I update it in the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the schedule package? You can schedule a task to run every day as follows:

```py
import schedule
import time
import pandas as pd

def get_global_data():
    data_df = pd.DataFrame()
    # Lot of DB reads and transformations
    return data_df

def update_global_data():
    global global_data
    global_data = get_global_data()

# Initialize global_data
global_data = get_global_data()

# Schedule the update function to run daily
schedule.every(1).day.at("00:00").do(update_global_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```